# Figure alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I am using the TikZ package to create braids for my 4th year project.

But everytime I hit the button to run the code, my braid jumps to the top of the page rather than sitting where I want it.

Can anyone help?

I am using the following packages,

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{braids}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \braid[rotate=90, line width=.4mm] a_1 a_2 a_2 a_1 a_2^-1;
        \end{tikzpicture}

    Figure~1 shows an example of a $3$-braid.
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX Stack Exchange! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Sounds like a variant of "figures have a tendency to surprise, by floating away". See the FAQ http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=floats.

Comment: What do you mean by `I hit the play button`? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I tend to agree with Ulrike: that's why the tag [tag:floats] seems to me appropriate.

Comment: `\begin{figure}[htp]` will first try placing the figure at the spot. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275

Comment: @HarishKumar The compile button in TeXworks is a green arrow, sort of like a play button.

Comment: In addition to the floating issue, avoid numbering things by hand: use `\caption{an example of a $3$-braid}` (or if you decide yo make it not a float. just remove the `figure` environment and use `\captionof{figure}{an example of a $3$-braid}`  (`capt-of` package)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant the compile button.

I managed to sort it using [htp] Thanks guys, I've not long started using Latex